# How to use siunitx to write 100 MBps?

Tags: siunitx

I want to show `100 MBps` (one hundred mega byte per second) in my article. How to make use of siunitx package to produce the rate correctly?

The following outputs are not what I want to get.

[image]

Comment: Why? You should not use `p` as a divisor symbol. Better use `/`. `/` is better because we already us it for numeric divisions and it is language independent. The correct unit symbol is `MB/s` not `MBps` nor `MBPs`. And there are units which start with a `P`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could do something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol,per-symbol = p}
\begin{document}
\SI{100}{\mega\byte\per\second}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would not like to encourage this, as it mixing up separate units (here bytes and seconds). I'd also point out that the correct prefix for binary units would be mebi not mega!

Comment: I will think of it later for my other projects even though your suggestion is absolutely correct.

Comment: In my experience, rate is often used with decimal units whereas capacity is often used with binary units. And I agree with not using the ps abbreviation for "per second", but the user gets to choose (alas).

Comment: Is `\SI{100}{MBps}` exactly identical to `\SI[per-mode=symbol,per-symbol = p]{100}{\mega\byte\per\second}`? I am afraid I will lose some useful features provided by the latter if I use the former.

Comment: The output is identical, but you loose the possibility for any automated reformatting. For example, if you decided (or perhaps a editor decided) to use `Mb\,s^{-1}` rather than `Mbps`, with the unit macros all you have to do is change an option.

Comment: About binary vs. decimal units the following link should be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix#Specific_units_of_IEC_60027-2_A.2_and_ISO.2FIEC_80000

Comment: Not as automated, but: `sed -e 's/{MBps}/{something else}/'`

Answer (score 9):

It is not a kosher SI unit, but since you and other people in your field use it anyway, just say `\SI{100}{MBps}`.

Comment: Actually I have tried this approach but I am not sure whether it is exactly equal to `\SI[per-mode=symbol,per-symbol = p]{100}{\mega\byte\per\second}`.

Comment: @Forgiver: It appears to be identical. In what way is it different? I may be missing a slight difference in spacing or something.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: I will ask the author for this doubt.