# siunitx declare unit

Tags: siunitx

I know how to declare a unit using `siunitx`

```
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \,]\hello{hello}
```

which just gives the written text hello. I also can combine it with the usual syntax like

```
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \,]\hello{\milli hello}
```

but how can I write a number inside a newly defined unit?

```
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \,]\hello{1e6 hello}
```

for example?

Comment: Look at the syntax on a random google result: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56051/problem-with-options-in-declaresiunit

Comment: It's not really clear what's the expected output from, say, `\SI{2}{\hello}`

Comment: Sorry but managed: I meant sth like this: \DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \,]
\test{\num[retain-unity-mantissa = false]{1e4}\per\centi\metre\cubed}

Comment: Voting to close as OP indicates that the problem was solved in the comments.