# How to typeset sampling rate using siunitx package?

Tags: siunitx, units

I want to show 1 GS/s (one giga sample per second) in my article. How to make use of siunitx package to produce the rate correctly?

I assume there to be something better, than `\SI{1}{GS/s}`.

I would like to write something like 
`\SI{1}{\giga\sample\per\second}`, but `\sample` is not defined in the package.

Related:

- [How to use siunitx to write 100 MBps?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55885/how-to-use-siunitx-to-write-100-mbps)

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Defining new unit (year, century) in siunitx](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6018)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This gets described on page 12 of the `siunitx` manual:

> New units are produced using the `\DeclareSIUnit` macro. < symbol > can
>   contain literal input, other units, multiple prefixes, powers and
>   `\per`, although literal text should not be intermixed with unit
>   macros. Units can be created with < options > from the usual list
>   understood by `siunitx`, and apply the specific unit macro only.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\sisetup{per-mode=symbol} % for the slashed version.
\DeclareSIUnit{\sample}{S}

\begin{document}
I would like to write something like \SI{1}{\giga\sample\per\second}

Problem could arise if you need to give some numbers in \si{\siemens}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Please add `\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}` to the answer to get exactly what I needed and I will accept the answer. I actually prefer the dash.